# Renaming the last column of a R dataFrame

Tags: r

I have a R dataFrame df with the following:

```
time      value      reference
 45        10           11
 22        12           10
 13        15           5
```

I would like to replace the last column of the dataFrame to obtain:

```
time      value        space
 45        10           11
 22        12           10
 13        15           5
```

I tried this:

```
colnames(length(colnames(df)))<-"space"
```

but it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: dataframes is the wrong tag for R.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use  `names()` instead:

```
names(df)[length(names(df))]<-"space"
```

Answer (score 8):

Marginally less typing:

```r
names(df)[ncol(df)] <- "space"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you need:

```
colnames(df)[ncol(df)] <- "space"
```